# MacBook Pro won’t charge after a power outage

Tags: macbook-pro, magsafe

Here’s the story: I left my MacBook Pro 13 mid 2010 plugged in for the night, and during the night there was a power outage. When I woke up there was no electricity, so I just unplugged the charger and used the laptop as usual. When the battery was at around 15% I finished working and closed the laptop.

A couple hours after that the power was back on and I decided to charge the laptop, which was completely discharged at that point, but when I connected it to the MagSafe, the LED didn’t light up and now the laptop isn’t showing any signs of life.

What I’ve tried:

- Using other sockets obviously
- New MagSafe charger
- SMC reset after charging the laptop for an hour (the LED wasn't lit up, so i guess it wasn’t charging)
- Tried disconnecting the battery from the logic board for half a minute

Any ideas what can be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Apple.SE! https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204267 Try all the points mentioned :)

Comment: What exact model of MBP is this? How old? Does the LED light up on the new MagSafe charger? You've tried another power outlet, or confirmed that other electrical devices work from the same socket? You've checked that the circuit breakers in the building have been reset?

Comment: Yep, checked all this before posting.

Comment: MacBook Pro 13 mid 2010. The LED on the new charger doesn’t light up. Yes, tried different outlets. Circuit breakers were reset, everything works fine except the laptop.